# Concerned I'm being made accessory to fraud and unsure what to do about it

Tags: management, ethics

I work as the accountant for a small company in the UK. Classically the company wasn't doing well and they hired a new manager to try and turn things around. The company owners/directors all live overseas and I've never spoken to them; I take all my instructions from this manager and he liaises with them.

Recently the company has been doing better. A few months back the manager said they'd ordered some new equipment on the company credit card to set up a home office because of the current situation. I asked for receipts and confirmation that the company owners were aware

Last month I was advised there would be an invoice arriving shortly for "some maintenance work" but it never materialised. Also last month I was asked (by the manager) to make a considerable bonus payment to the new manager because it's part of their contract that they get 10% of company profits every month that the company makes a profit. I think this should be a yearly thing as the trade is very seasonal and there haven't been any prop up payments in loss making months, but never having seen the contract I don't know the specifics.

This month the manager said "my bonus this month will mean I go over the upper tax threshold and I'll lose my child benefit. Is there any way I can get around that like putting my partner on the payroll and paying them instead?". I was incredibly upset by this, and have no desire to be involved in anything to this effect. I strongly believe that anyone in an upper tax bracket can easily afford to forego a benefit worth at most 1.5% of their earnings; less in a dual income household and I feel it's deeply unethical. I said I couldn't help with that sort of accounting advice because tax was not my speciality and I didn't want to be appraised of any such ideas. I was then asked whether it would be an option for the partner to set up a consultancy and charge the company a fee. Again I said I wasn't best placed to advise and they needed a tax accountant, not a management accountant

Today I was told "oh, I've received an invoice from a building company but they don't have bank details so I'm going to cut them a cheque". The invoice itemisation says "maintenance to office unit" but we occupy a unit where the maintenance aspects are the landlord's responsibility so I'm not quite sure what work has gone on. I'm not party to any of the financial side of this transaction; I just asked for direction on how to account for it. With the current pandemic situation I work exclusively from home so I don't know whether works have been done. My concern there is that recently this manager has spoken of a need to replace their house doors because they're in bad shape, but the quotes were too high so they're "doing it diy". This is circumstantial at best but the coincidence troubles me

I don't feel like I have any relationship enough with the business owners to just approach them outright and ask if all this has been discussed and sanctioned. I'm not yet in receipt of an invoice from the partner's consulting company but I'm concerned I will be. Other things don't quite sit right; The banking is set up so that any one person (out of me, the manager, the director) can use company funds without input or confirmation from others, something I railed against at the time. I suspect covid support loans may have been applied for even though it seems the pandemic is responsible for the improvement in trade

A side complication is that my own partner also works for the company and I don't want their working life to be made difficult if I raise issue with things I think are going on.

I feel like if I say anything to anyone it can only make a situation worse, and the only recourse is to leave or ask to be downgraded to a point where I'm not responsible for any payments or accounting at that level - but then I feel like I'm being made to suffer because of someone else's actions

Comment: Could you clarify whether you are a qualified accountant, or a _person who does the accounts_? I've heard of situations where non-qualified people are hired to do the job precisely because the owner expects that a qualified person would know that what they are being asked is improper.

Answer (score 21):

Think about this from the owner's point of view. Why do they have an accountant instead of just giving the manager signing authority on the chequing account? Why does this manager have to bring these invoices to you and get you to ok things, instead of just helping themselves to the money? Why do they have to ask you to set things up? Because the owners want a layer of protection. They want someone with integrity and someone who knows what the right and wrong ways are to do things. Someone who says "well actually I think you're supposed to pay your taxes, and this company only gives salary to people who do things for it."

What is happening right now is precisely and exactly what you are in that chair for. Tell them everything, report what is happening, ask them what they want done. If you don't like what they want done, you may have to leave the job. If they fire you for double checking before paying someone who isn't working, or paying invoices for work that probably wasn't done, then thank your lucky stars because if the owners don't mind misbehaviour like that then sooner or later you would end up in front of your professional body.

Yes, having your partner's income be on the line as well as your own makes the stakes higher. Nevertheless, do what they hired you to do: let them know someone is trying to pull a fast one. Chances are, they'll be grateful, and they'll pat themselves on the back that they had a good accountant to protect them from this bad manager.

Answer (score 14):

> I don't feel like I have any relationship enough with the business owners to just approach them outright and ask if all this has been discussed and sanctioned.

It doesn't matter.

At the very least, you need to inform them that the new bank account was set up in such a way that any single signatory can rob the business's account blind, and that you strongly disagree with that decision.

Plus, if the paper position for his partner is still a major issue for the manager, you may want to inform the owners of that plan as well.

And you need to tell them all of this via email, that you want them to acknowledge and respond to. This will cover yourself in case the manager decides to pilfer the new account. Plus, if the manager hasn't given up on his defrauding scheme, this will dissuade the owners from asking you to go along with it, since they will see that you've already created a paper trail on this issue.

Either the owners will like your intervention, or they won't. Either they'll keep you employed, or they won't. Either they'll keep your partner employed, or they won't. You can not control their reaction. But at the same time, if you're an absentee owner who lives far away, having a local accountant you can trust to keep an eye on your business can be also very valuable. So it's anybody's guess to how they will react.

Now once you've taken this first step with the bank account, the other issues should work themselves out as well. Because the manager knows that if you can't stay quiet about the bank account issue, he also knows that you won't able to stay quiet about the other irregularities as well.

Comment: even if everyone is 100% trustworthy the single signatory issue is dangerous in the case of an identity theft getting access to all the money

Answer (score 2):

It may be possible to take an approach where you aren't the accuser...for example, ask what the procedure would be to add the partner as an employee or supplier, and since it's for tax purposes, is there any tax implication to the company.  Let them know the new manager has already informed you of the 10% monthly profit sharing in his contract and just wants to change the payout details.  Maybe separately, ask the same person if there's some way to protect or insure the bank account that multiple people currently have unfettered access to.  Maybe mention that you could use guidance on a few things, since up to now you've been following a particular comfortable set of rules which have more checks and balances than the current style.

This allows you to bring some of these things to the attention of somebody who can verify the details of what this guy is claiming without actually accusing him of wrongdoing.  If the home office sees no problem with it, they can tell you how to do it, and you have documentation of the approval (or complicity) that largely absolves you of blame for things you don't actually know for a fact are illegal.